# bindValue does not escape

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

I read a comment at php.net:

> Although `bindValue()` escapes quotes it does not escape "%" and "_", so be careful when using `LIKE`. A malicious parameter full of %%% can dump your entire database if you don't escape the parameter yourself. PDO does not provide any other escape method to handle it.

So is it really doesn't escape the % and _ ? What could be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment says, it's really only an issue for `LIKE` queries.

It depends on your database on how you have to escape those values. If normal backslash escaping works (as in MySQL), then use:

```
$like = addcslashes($like, "%_");
```

Alternatively it's probably best to be lazy and just strip those meta characters out:

```
$like = strtr($like, "%_", "  ");
```